# Mostrar registros de una BD en JSON

Tags: php, json, webservice, android-volley

Lo que pasa que es que quiero traer los registros de mi bd mysql a mi app en android estoy utilizando volley y mi web service queda de la siguiente forma

```
<?php 


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){



    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

    include('database.php');
    $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $host_user, $host_password, $database);


    $obID =mysqli_fetch_array (mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_usuario, nombre, email, password FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '$usuario'"));
    $id=  $obID['id_usuario'];


    $fetch = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT lugar, fecha FROM historial where id_usuario = '$id'");

   while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {


        $respuesta[]= $datos;
        $respuesta[] = $datos;



   }
```

//   $datos = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch);

```
  // $respuesta['lugar']=  $datos;
//mysqli_close($conn); 

   echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

}

Realice pruebas con este codigo y me daba un json de la siguiente forma

```
[
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 01:40:46",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 01:40:46"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 01:40:46",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 01:40:46"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 11:23:39",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 11:23:39"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 11:23:39",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 11:23:39"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 14:17:16",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 14:17:16"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 14:17:16",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 14:17:16"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 14:32:02",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 14:32:02"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 14:32:02",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 14:32:02"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 14:53:13",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 14:53:13"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 14:53:13",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 14:53:13"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:34:50",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:34:50"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:34:50",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:34:50"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:43:22",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:43:22"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:43:22",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:43:22"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:50:40",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:50:40"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:50:40",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:50:40"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:50:41",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:50:41"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:50:41",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:50:41"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:52:38",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:52:38"
},
{
  "0":"Plaza Comercial",
  "lugar":"Plaza Comercial",
  "1":"2019-12-28 17:52:38",
  "fecha":"2019-12-28 17:52:38"
}
```

]

Como pueden ver hay 20 registros en el json pero en mi BASE DE DATOS HAY SOLO 10

[image: Tabla de la BD]

Mi duda es como puedo mejorar el JSON por que lo puedo pasar perfectamente a mi APP ya lo consegui los almacene en un recyclerView pero no se por que el json genera 20 registros osea los duplica si alguien me podria ayudar a solucinar esto se los agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta es fácil: has duplicado la instrucción `$respuesta[] = $datos;` en tu bucle `while`:

```
   while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        $respuesta[] = $datos;
        $respuesta[] = $datos;
   }
```

Elimina una de las dos y ya no te saldrán esos duplicados que comentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, no me había fijado de ese inconveniente, debi darme mas tiempo a meditar el error antes de escribir aqui, estaba muy sencillo duplique la linea accidentalmente como me comentas. Gracias por la rapida respuesta.

Comment: No te tortures, la de horas de trabajo que se pierden en estas nimiedades. Mejor preguntar que perder más tiempo con ello sin llegar a verlo. Piensa que a los que estamos aquí nos ha pasado montones de veces y estaremos encantados de ayudarte. Muchas veces es simple cuestión de perspectiva o de hacer otra cosa en medio para despejarte